# WKWebView add to subview, and set size equal to parent?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, wkwebview

I'm developing an app that displays HTML content stored locally.

My storyboard scene consists of a customised menu view ('MyMenuBar'), and a 'containerView', where I would like the HTML to be loaded. Both of these items are properly constrained in the storyboard.

I'm attempting to use WKWebView, as recommend by Apple. I want to add the WKWebView as a subview of the 'containerView', and give it identical constraints, however I cannot get this right. Content drops off the edge of the screen, or doesn't display at all.

Here is what I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var MyMenuBar: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

...
var myWebView: WKWebView?

//View did load...
webViewWK = WKWebView()

containerView.addSubview(myWebView!)
myWebView?.frame = containerView.frame

myWebView?.load(localFileURL!)
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. I have tried:

```
view.insertSubview(myWebView!, belowSubview: MyMenuBar)
```

and

```
containerView = myWebView!
```

But these display nothing. I have also tried:

```
myWebView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

However, I still experience the same unusual layout issue with content incorrectly scaled, and falling off the screen.

I can solve this problem by simply using UIWebView on the storyboard, but I want the performance and future-proofing of WKWebView, and can't understand why I can't add it programmatically with correct constraints.

I am using Xcode 8.0 and Swift 3

Many thanks

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me is to specify the autoresizing mask in addition to the coords for the sublayout, hinted from [Sparky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6801926/sparky)'s answer

```
myWebView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
myWebView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: containerView.frame.size)
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. The webview is still full screen regardless of how I configure the container view. Mind to share your code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the line:

```
MyWebView?.frame = containerView.frame
```

Remember that when you add a subview to a container view, the frame for the subview must be specified in coordinates relative to the parent view. If your container view had coordinates for its origin of (100, 100), for example, this means that the web view will have its origin at an offset from the container view of (100, 100), not at the origin of the container view.

The correct way to specify the frame would be:

```
myWebView?.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: containerView.frame.size)
```

I think this should fix your issue. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately this has not resolved the issue. The trailing space to superview constraint is broken every time, without explanation in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put you code into viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad. It works for me with Sparky's answer :

```
videoWebKitView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: videoContainer.frame.size))

videoContainer.addSubview(videoWebKitView)
```

It doesn't work for me until I move my code.